# Detect browser css3 supports with Modernizr

Tags: modernizr

I want to check the client browser's css3 support on my website and if it doesn't support css3 I want to show the user a message.

Here is the code I've written to check border radius on the user's browser. It doesn't work properly all of the time though. I've checked this on Mac with the latest version of Chrome (it works), but at home on pc with the latest version of Chrome it doesn't show any message.

```
    if (!Modernizr.borderRadius) {
               $(function brwsalert(){
           $("<div>")
           .css({
       'position': 'absolute',
       'top': '0px',
         'left': '0px',
         backgroundColor: 'black',
        'opacity': '0.75',
         'width': '100%',
         'height': $(window).height(),
         zIndex: 5000
        })
       .appendTo("body");

             $("<div><br/><p style='direction: rtl;'>بازدید کننده گرامی،<br/>جهت مشاهده وب سایت می بایست از مرورگرهای بروز استفاده نمایید. جهت دریافت نسخه بروز مرورگر دلخواه بر روی آیکون آن کلیک نمایید.</p><br/><p style='text-align:center;'><a href='https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/'><img src='images/chrome.png' width='64px' height='64px'></a>  <a href='https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/'> <img src='images/firefox.png'/></a>  <a href='http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/download-ie'><img src='images/ie.png'/></a>  <a href='http://www.opera.com/'><img src='images/opera.png' width='64px' height='64px'></a>  </p>")      
        .css({
         backgroundColor: 'white',
         'top': '50%',
         'left': '50%',
         marginLeft: -210,
         marginTop: -100,
         width: 410,
         paddingRight: 10,
         height: 200,
         'position': 'absolute',
         zIndex: 6000
       })
       .appendTo("body");
           });  
          }
```

Comment: Did you try using the Chrome console to check the JavaScript? What did the logs say?

Comment: Also, try just showing a single one-line alert, or console.log, to narrow down your troubleshooting. I.e. is it Modernizr.borderRadius reporting an unexpected value, or an issue with the following code.

Comment: Dear @Alex yes I've tried

Comment: Dear @Adam I've tried console.log(Modernizr.borderRadius); and I get undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the syntax should be `Modernizr.borderradius`

I have tested this with Modernizr 2.6.2, this works correctly in Chrome, and Safari for Windows, whereas `Modernizr.borderRadius` returns undefined in both cases. I don't currently have a Mac to test on.